# Error submitting form with date field

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime-format

I get the following error in a page where I use a datepicker. No matter what day is inserted, this error happens:

14-Fev-1991. What is that? Today is 14-Fev but not 1991! What should I do?

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

[FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) +3211050
System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider) +28
System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +290

[FormatException: 14-02-1991 is not a valid value for DateTime.]
System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +452
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute.SetupConversion() +626
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute.IsValid(Object value) +38
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified your default DateTimeFormat? Hope its not using US format

This is for US, you need to set it as per your requirement.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="de-DE"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This might help further http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647353.aspx

Comment: it's not working. But why do you think this could with the problem? The year 1991 has nothing to do this and 14-Feb is today.

Comment: @Fabio, I don't think it's anything to do with the year. I think that its trying to convert 14 to month and Feb, which is 2 to the day in the month, so instead of dd-mm-yyyy, its reading it as mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: @Fabio, what sort of date picker control are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery datepicker and it was working fine. Now it's working again and I did not change anything!... This looks like a server problem to me, but I hope it doesn't happen again. Thumbs up to you anyway. And thanks for trying to help ;)